# Issues on Console : Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, console

I'm having an issue error says "Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform" and I don't know how to solve it.
I see that the issues are from bundle.js but I'm not sure what to do .
If anyone know, please guide me through. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: That message tells you **exactly** what to do - and if it's not **your** code triggering it, then my advice is to either a) find out which library it is and inform the library maintainer of their poor choices, or b) ignore the issue, unless something actually doesn't work